# GCP : Cloud function & memorystore zone issue

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-memorystore, google-vpc

I have a **memorystore (standard tier)** in **us-central1-b (master) & us-central1-a (replica)** zone. I am connecting to memorystore instance via cloud function & a Serverless VPC. All I know is my CF is running in us-central1 region. Is there some way to keep both cloud function & memorystore instance in same zone?

As of now I can specify where my master node of memorystore instance reside, but no option for cloudfunction to make it run in the zone I want. If I can get info on zone of CF, I can make memorystore run in same zone as CF.

Answer (score 2):

You can not specify which zone Cloud Functions run in.  From the docs:

> Cloud Functions is regional, which means the infrastructure that runs
>   your Cloud Function is located in a specific region and is managed by
>   Google to be redundantly available across all the zones within that
>   region.

Another quote is:

> Zones have high-bandwidth, low-latency network connections to other
>   zones in the same region.

and finally ...

> Locations (zones) within regions tend to have round-trip network
>   latencies of under <1ms on the 95th percentile.

What this all says to me is that a call to Memorystore from a Cloud Function where both are in the same region should not incur a meaningful latency overhead.

References:

- [Cloud Functions Locations](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/locations)
- [Regions and Zones](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/)
- [Geography and Regions](https://cloud.google.com/docs/geography-and-regions)